# Communication between NodeJS and webpage

Tags: node.js

I built simple weather webpage basing on the tutorial. and I have a webpage with below JS code;
I have also Node JS code( on the bottom) for temperature and pressure sensor written with Johnny-Five. This works perfectly but what I wanna do is display readouts from the sensors setup with NodeJS on the webpage. What is the best approach to do that? I tried to setup this with websocket but it was not really working.

```
    let weather = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    fetchWeather: function (city) {
      fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=" + this.apiKey
      ).then((response) => {
        
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
    },
    displayWeather: function (data) {
      const { name } = data;
      const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
      const { temp, humidity, pressure } = data.main;
      const { speed } = data.wind;
      const temperatura = Math.round(temp);
      document.querySelector(".miasto").innerText = "Pogoda w  " + name;
      document.querySelector(".icon").src =
        "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
      document.querySelector(".opis").innerText = description;
      document.querySelector(".temperatura").innerText = temperatura + "°C";
      document.querySelector(".wilgotnosc").innerText =
        "Wilgotność: " + humidity + "%";
        document.querySelector(".cisnienie").innerText =
        "Ciśnienie: " + pressure + "HPa";
      document.querySelector(".wiatr").innerText =
        "Prędkość wiatru: " + speed + " km/h";
      document.querySelector(".pogoda").classList.remove("loading");
      document.body.style.backgroundImage =
        "url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?" + name + "')";
    },
    search: function () {
      this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
    },
  };
  
  document.querySelector(".search button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    weather.search();
  });
  
  document
    .querySelector(".search-bar")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.key == "Enter") {
        weather.search();
      }
    });
    weather.fetchWeather("Katowice");
 



    var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board(
    {
        port: "COM4"
     }
);

board.on("ready", function() {
  var multi = new five.Multi({
    controller: "BMP180",
    freq: 500
  });

  multi.on("change", function() {
    console.log("Termometr");
    console.log("  Temperatura      : ", this.thermometer.celsius, " ℃");
    console.log("--------------------------------------");

var pressure2 = Math.round(this.barometer.pressure*100, 1)/10;

    console.log("Barometr");
    console.log("  Ciśnienie     : ", pressure2, " HPa" );
    console.log("--------------------------------------");
   

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. Quite simple but mybe it will help someone here

Data which I am sending are

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8085 })
var obj = {
  press: "69",
  temp: "24"
}

wss.on("connection", ws => {
   ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
} );
```

And I get it:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8085");

ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
  console.log("We are connected");

  ws.addEventListener("message", (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.data));
  });
});
```